# Executar função depois de carregar página com Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, alert

Estou tentando executar uma função que da um alerta na tela depois que o contudo é carregado, porem, não estou tendo sucesso com o ng-init pois usando o ng-init ele da o alerta e a tela fica em branco e só carrega depois de clicar no botão 'OK'.
Existe uma forma de executar uma função só depois que o conteúdo da ng-view foi carregado ?

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com a [documentação](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView):

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
    //Executar depois de carregado
});
```

Comment: Também não deu certo, acabei 'resolvendo' com o $timeout, mas obrigado pela ajuda!